# std::cerr,std::clogの違いについて

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

2017-04-17-20:00

std::cerrについて調べていたところ以下のようなコード
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr)
に行き当たったのですが、その挙動が理解できずに悩んでいます。

ソースコードは以下です。

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
void f()
{
    std::cout << "Output from thread...";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << "...thread calls flush()" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(f);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::clog << "This output from main is not tie()'d to cout\n";
    std::cerr << "This output is tie()'d to cout\n";
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 でコンパイルし、実際に手元の環境(Ubuntu16.04)で動かしてみた所出力は以下のようになりました。

```
This output from main is not tie()'d to cout
Output from thread...This output is tie()'d to cout
...thread calls flush()
```

cerrはバッファリングを行わず、clogはバッファリングを行うとの認識だったのですが、この出力結果を見るに、clogへの出力はバッファリングされず、mainスレッドの待機命令を無視して真っ先に出力されているように見えます。また、その後に関数f()の一行目が実行され、t1スレッドも待機に入り、先に待機がとけたmainスレッドでcerrにバッファリングされていたメッセージが出力されているように見えます。
何故このような挙動になり、僕の理解はどのように間違っているのでしょうか。
どなたかご存じの方ご教授願います。

21:20
質問投稿の後にも試行錯誤しつつ調べていたのですが、一部解決したのでここに報告させていただきます。
"Output from thread..."よりも"Thid output ..."のほうが早く出力されていたのはf()内一行目ではflushが起きていないためでした。
ここでバッファに溜まったテキストはcerrの手前で吐き出されていますが、これはcerrが呼び出し直後にまずcout.flushを呼び出すためのようです。以下参考URL
(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr)

ただバッファリングされるはずのclogがそのまま出力されているのは未だ解決出来ていません。
"\n"による行バッファリングの可能性も指摘していただいたのですが、"\n"を取り除いても出力は行われるのでこれが原因でもないようです。

21:43
clogですが、試行錯誤の結果、既にcoutにバッファリングされているデータのflushは行わないものの、clog自体のflushはしているということがわかりました。「clogはバッファリングをする」という文言の意味を取り違えていたようです。問題解決に協力してくださったmetropolisさん、ありがとうございました。

21:55
clogについてですが、
cppreference.com（信用度が足りないらしくリンクが投稿できないので、サイト名だけで失礼します）
には勝手にflushされない旨が書いてあるのでやはり不可解な挙動のようです。
追加で調べて進展したらまた追記します。

04-18-12:45
解決しました。詳しくはベストアンサーをご覧ください。Hidekiさんありがとうございました。

Comment: flush すれば良いのではないでしょうか。`std::cout << "Output from thread..." << std::flush;`

Comment: 回答ありがとう御座います。coutがバッファリングを伴うのでflushしなければいけないということは分かるのですが、clogとcerrの方の挙動が理解できないということで困っております。上記の例では、clogはバッファリングを伴うはずなのにflushしなくとも真っ先に出力され、cerrはバッファリングを伴わないのですぐに出力されるはずなのに、clogよりも大幅に遅れて出力されているという部分です。

Comment: clog で newline(`\n`) を出力していますので flush される事になります(行バッファリング)。

Comment: @metropolis
記法に不慣れなため非常に読みづらいコードになってしまっていることをお詫び申し上げます。

Comment: @metropolis 
先のコードから"\n"を除いて少し改変を加えたコード（以下）

`int main(){
      std::thread t1(f);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
      std::clog << "clog output from main is not tied to cout  ";
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
      std::cerr << "cerr output is tied to cout\n";
      t1.join();       
      return 0;
    }`

を実行してみたのですが、下記のような出力になりました。

`clog output from main is not tied to cout  Output from thread......thread calls flush()
cerr output is tied to cout`

上を見ると行バッファリングは起こっていないように思うのですが、c++のiostreamにも行バッファリングはあるのでしょうか。

Comment: ああ、すみません、clog の説明を読み間違えていました。

Comment: 質問欄のサンプルプログラムに付けられた説明文 `output to stderr via cerr flushes out the pending output on cout, while output to stderr via clog does not` が答えになっているかと思います。

Comment: 再度すみません、既に質問欄に追加済みだったのですね…

Comment: @metoropolis
ありがとう御座います！まさに求めていた答えはそれだったみたいです。
とても助かりました。

Comment: @metropolis 
こちらこそ混乱させてしまい申し訳ありません。

Comment: いえ、こちらこそ間違いを伝えてしまい申し訳ありません。[std::clog, std::wclog - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/clog) には `these streams are not automatically flushed ...` と記載されているのですが、cerr と同様にバッファリングはされない様ですね。

Comment: @metropolis
やはりclogの内容が勝手にflushされているのは少し気持ち悪い挙動なんですね。もう少し調べてみて、何かわかったら追記しようと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/) にある C++仕様のドラフト (n4618) を見てみましたが、std::clog について書かれているのは、27.4.2 Narrow stream object の

> ostream cerr;
>   The object cerr controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object stderr, declared in  (27.11.1).
>   After the object cerr is initialized, cerr.flags() & unitbuf is nonzero and cerr.tie() returns &cout. Its state is otherwise the same as required for basic_ios::init (27.5.5.2).
>
> ostream clog;
>   The object clog controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object stderr, declared in  (27.11.1).

と、27.5.3.1.6 Class ios_base::Init の

> Init();
>   Effects: Constructs an object of class Init. Constructs and initializes the objects cin, cout, cerr, clog, wcin, wcout, wcerr, and wclog if they have not already been constructed and initialized.
>
> ~Init();
>   Effects: Destroys an object of class Init. If there are no other instances of the class still in existence, calls cout.flush(), cerr.flush(), clog.flush(), wcout.flush(), wcerr.flush(), wclog.flush().

くらいで、他には見つかりませんでした。clog のバッファは、いつ flush されるか、どこにも記述がないので、実装依存と解釈するのが正しいと思います。

つまり

- cerr については、少なくとも出力ごとには必ず flush される。
- clog については、いつ flush されるか、わからない。出力ごとかもしれないし、あとで、まとめてかもしれない。

です。cppreference.com の記述は、ちょっと紛らわしいと思います。

Comment: 標準規格ではflushのタイミングが定められていないんですね。
実装依存の仕様がcppreference.comにのっているのは少し怖い話です。
とてもわかり易い回答をいただきありがとうございました！

Comment: 妄想するに標準エラーへの出力に相反する要求があって [ログ出力に使いたいので性能が欲しい] [エラー出力に使いたいので直ちに表示して欲しい] 前者な場合は `clog` 後者な場合は `cerr` を排他的に使え、ってことなのではないか、と。 `clog` と `cerr` の両者を同時に使うことはあまり想定されていないのではないかな・・・正しく `clog` を閉じたなら全データが書き出されていればそれで良いので `clog` に対するバッファリングに対して詳細を決める必要は無い、んでしょ。